# React unit testing Leaflet

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, leaflet, jestjs, enzyme

I have problem with unit testing Map component.

My class component:

```
componentDidMount() {
    const { zoom, data, center } = this.props;
    const { activeButton } = this.state;
    if (data[activeButton] != null) {
      this.map = map('map', {
        center: data[activeButton].points ? data[activeButton].points[0] : center,
        zoom,
        layers: [tileLayer(...SETTINGS.mapTileLayer)],
      });
      if (data[activeButton].points != null) {
        this.addPolyline(data[activeButton].points);
      }
    }
  }

  addPolyline = (points: Points) => {
    if (this.polyline != null) {
      this.map.removeLayer(this.polyline);
      this.map.removeLayer(this.marker.start);
      this.map.removeLayer(this.marker.stop);
    }

    if (points != null && points[0] != null) {
      this.polyline = new Polyline(points, SETTINGS.polyline);

      this.marker.start = new Marker(points[0]);
      this.marker.stop = new Marker(points[points.length - 1]);

      this.polyline.addTo(this.map);
      this.marker.start.addTo(this.map);
      this.marker.stop.addTo(this.map);

      this.map.panTo(points[0]);
    }
  };
```

Unit test with Jest and Enzyme

```
function getComponent(mockData) {
  return <Map data={mockData} />;
}

const mockData = [
  { id: 0, name: '1', distance: '1', points: [[0, 0], [1, 1]] },
  { id: 1, name: '2', distance: '2', points: [[0, 0], [1, 1]] },
];

describe('LastActivity component', () => {  
  it('button click', () => {
    const wrapper = mount(getComponent(mockData), { attachTo: document.body });

...etc...
});
```

With this test I get

> TypeError: Cannot read property '_layerAdd' of null
>
> this.polyline.**addTo**(this.map);

When I comment out line this line

> this.polyline.addTo(this.map);

Everything works fine and tests pass

package.json:

```
"enzyme-adapter-react-16": "1.2.0",
"enzyme": "3.4.4",
"react": "16.4.2",
"react-dom": "16.4.2",
"leaflet": "1.3.4",
"jest": "23.5.0",
"jest-cli": "23.5.0",
```

Comment: have you tried looking what you are passing on chrome's console ? It could be that you are not passing anything to this.polyline? It seems on their docs, that Polyline doesn't have this method to test out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see a bunch of related issues on leaflet's github. The maintainer seems to have something against frameworks.
Check out https://react-leaflet.js.org/ that should work better with react.